How can we motivate the $te^{rt}$ solution pattern in differential equations?
The workhorse of ordinary differential equations is of course the exponential function $f(t) = Ae^{rt}$, which has the amazing property that $$D^nf = r^nf$$ making its appearance in differential equations well understood.
When such a solution is "missing", the go-to is $$g(t) = Ate^{rt}$$ which appears in all sorts of places (a second solution for homogeneous equations, resonant forcing in second order equations, missing eigenvalues - all of which are forms of the characteristic polynomial having repeated roots.)
It's easy to prove the correctness of solutions using $g$: just take the derivative.  Is there a way to motivate it or some type of intuition behind it? It seems like a black box that yes, I can prove works but I have no idea why the equations behave this way.  This is in stark contrast to the exponential function without the $t$ factor, which is well motivated and intuitive.
How can you explain the $te^{rt}$ pattern, even informally? Why do some equations have it as part of their solution?
This question is about intuition and motivation, not a source or derivation, where are discussed here.

Do you already know about generalized eigenvectors in Linear Algebra? In some sense, that's the more general origin of this phenomenon.

@MarkS. In the context of exploring this, I've read about generalized eigenvectors. The most intuitive definition: If $A$ has eigenvector $v$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then $w$ is a generalized eigenvector of $A$ if $$Aw = \lambda w + kv$$ for some scalar $k$.  (Is that correct?) Agreed that better intuition there would help here too!

Yes. Take the case of distinct roots $r$ and $s$ of the indicial equation, so you have the general solution $c_1e^{rt} + c_2e^{st}$. Now this means $e^{st}-e^{rt}$ is a solution, and so is $\dfrac{e^{st}-e^{rt}}{s-r}$. What’s the limit as $s\to r$?

As an analogy, if a 2nd order linear recursion $x_n = ax_{n-1} + bx_{n-2}$ has a characteristic polynomial $t^2 = at + b$ with a double root $r$ that is not $0$, then two basic linearly independent solutions are $r^n$ and $nr^{n}$.  To motivate that second solution, which is the analogue of $te^{rt}$ in the linear ODE setting, if the characteristic polynomial has distinct roots $r$ and $s$ then a solution to the recursion is $r^n - s^n$, which can be rescaled to the solution $(r^n - s^n)/(r-s)$, and as $s \to r$ this becomes $nr^{n-1}$, which can be rescaled to $nr^n$. Voila!

One extra step would be helpful here: the reason we consider this specific linear combination is that it fixes the initial conditions $y(0) = 0$ and $y'(0) = 1$.

@QiaochuYuan Can you expand on that? I'm intrigued by what you write.  Why would we want to fix $y'(0)=1$ - why those conditions in particular?

@SRobertJames: it's just for convenience. You can do the calculation with general initial conditions (this is done in the linked question). The important thing is that they should be fixed, independent of $r$ and $s$.

A key to this is the use of the differentiation operator and the Exponential Shift Theorem:
$$ P(D) (\exp(r t) u) = \exp(r t) P(D + r) u $$
where $D$ is the operator of differentiation with respect to the variable $t$, $u$ is any (sufficiently smooth) function of $t$, and $P$ is any polynomial.
The point is that we already know how to solve equations involving monomials in $D$, and the Exponential Shift Theorem lets us transfer that to polynomials.
For example, if $P(x)$ has a double root $x=\lambda$, $P(x+\lambda)$ has a double root $0$, and thus is divisible by $x^2$.  Thus $P(D + \lambda) = Q(D) D^2 $ for some polynomial $Q$.  Now $D^2 f = f'' = 0$ if $f$ is a polynomial of degree $\le 1$, so those satisfy $P(D+\lambda) f = 0$, and then Exponential Shift says $P(D)(exp(\lambda t) f) = exp(\lambda t) P(D+\lambda) f = 0$, i.e. a polynomial of degree $\le 1$ times $\exp(\lambda t)$ is a solution of the differential equation $P(D) y = 0$.
